# How to pass data of an object to HTML file

Tags: javascript, html

I have few posts in my app, and I want that when user selects one of them, he to be redirected to a `Post.html` page which contains all details about that specific product. I have two methods, `createPost()` for creating a product dynamically where I pass `postId` in order to keep track of that product, and `getPosts()` to get the posts from database. I am saving all posts in an array in `localStorage` to have data about the selected product in `Post.html`. I added an `addEventListener()` but not sure how to use it. The problem is that I am stuck how to get the information of that post and pass it to `Post.html`.

```
function getPosts() {
  firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("products")
    .get().then(snapshot => {
      let products = [];
      snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
        products.push(doc.data());
        createPost(
          doc.data().title,
          doc.data().description,
          doc.data().price,
          doc.data().postId
        );
      });
      localStorage.setItem(`${products}`, JSON.stringify(products));
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

```
function createPost(title, description, price, postId) {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute("class", "product-home-show");

  ......

  div.appendChild(divSellerRoundImage);
  div.appendChild(divSellerName);
  div.appendChild(divProductDescription);
  div.appendChild(divProductName);
  div.appendChild(divProductPrice);

  productsCollection.appendChild(div);

  div.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // console.log(localStorage.getItem());
    // window.location.href = "post.html";
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get data from localStorage on another page. Use `localStorage.getItem(keyName);` Also keep in mind the first argument to setItem is the key name. I'd recommend changing your code to: `localStorage.setItem("products", JSON.stringify(products));`. Then you'll be able to retrieve your product list with they key "products."

Also, if you're saving an object, you'll need to parse it since it will be saved as a string. You can use `JSON.parse`

For example:

```
var retrievedData = localStorage.getItem("products");
var productListObject = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
```

You can save the selected post ID in another value in local storage, or a cookie. Lastly, you may want to consider using sessionStorage if you don't need the data stored after the session is over. See [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage#:%7E:text=sessionStorage%20is%20similar%20to%20localStorage,over%20page%20reloads%20and%20restores.) for more information